# FormulaR1C1 and "=SUMIFS("

Tags: excel, sumifs, vba

I'm trying to add up all the units that are in occupied locations in a specific location type depending on `BUcode` and `Division` of the business.

> **Note:**
>   - Variables *binshelv* and *occupied* are defined names in the worksheet.
>   - Variables *Division* and *BUcode* are defined in the parent code that calls and passes along the values to this procedure.

Below is the code I am trying to enter:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(" & _
        "" & BUcode & "=Overall," & _
        "if(" & _
                "" & Division & "=Overall, " & _
                "SUMIFS(" & _
                        "DataDump[On Hand Qty (Units)]," & _
                        "DataDump[Occupied?], occupied," & _
                        "DataDump[Location Short Description], binshelv" & _
                ")," & _
                "Sumifs(" & _
                        "DataDump[On Hand Qty (Units)]," & _
                        "DataDump[Occupied?], occupied," & _
                        "DataDump[Location Short Description], binshelv," & _
                        "DataDump[Division Code], " & DivCode & "," & _
                ")" & _
        ")," & _
        "SUMIFS(" & _
                "DataDump[On Hand Qty (Units)]," & _
                "DataDump[Business Unit]," & BUcode & "," & _
                "DataDump[Location Short Description], binshelv" & _
        ")" & _

    ")"
```

Why I'm currently getting `Error '1004'`?

Comment: There is not enough information for us to debug this.

Comment: What info should I additionally provide?

Comment: Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need to tell us, what the two variables are declared, what value is assigned or set?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is that your formula does not equate to a valid string.  If you copy and paste the following code into the VBA editor you will see that strFormula does not equate to a valid string.  This means you've got an error in the formula.  One thing to remember is that you need to double quote quotation marks in your formula, or use escape characters, to use literal quotes in a string.

Play around with trying to get "strFormula =" to equate to a valid string.

```
Sub aa()

    Dim strFormula As String
    Dim binshelv, occupied, Division, BUcode As String

    ' **--- Get this line to equate to a valid string**
    strFormula = _
    "=IF(" & _
    "" & BUcode & "=Overall," & _
    "if(" & _
            "" & Division & "=Overall, " & _
            "SUMIFS(" & _
                    "DataDump[On Hand Qty (Units)]," & _
                    "DataDump[Occupied?], occupied," & _
                    "DataDump[Location Short Description], binshelv" & _
            ")," & _
            "Sumifs(" & _
                    "DataDump[On Hand Qty (Units)]," & _
                    "DataDump[Occupied?], occupied," & _
                    "DataDump[Location Short Description], binshelv," & _
                    "DataDump[Division Code], " & DivCode & "," & _
            ")" & _
    ")," & _
    "SUMIFS(" & _
            "DataDump[On Hand Qty (Units)]," & _
            "DataDump[Business Unit]," & BUcode & "," & _
            "DataDump[Location Short Description], binshelv" & _
    ")" & _
    ")"

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = strFormula
End Sub
```

Using double quotes to express a literal quote mark turns

```
=SUMIFS(C8:C11,A8:A11,"colACriteria",B8:B11,"ColBCriteria")
```

into

```
"=SUMIFS(C8:C11,A8:A11,""colACriteria"",B8:B11,""ColBCriteria"")"
```